# Exception: No route to host when a user ads a comment which is sent to the server

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This happens very rarely, and I have not been able to reproduce it, but the below code sometimes gets an exception from no host.  Here is the code:

```
public class AddComment extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... theParams) 
    {
        String myUrl = theParams[0];
        final String comment = theParams[1];
        final String user_id = theParams[2];
        final String problem_id = theParams[3];
        final String recent_topic_id = theParams[4];

        String charset = "UTF-8";           
        String response = null;

        try 
        {                           
            String query = String.format("comment=%s&user_id=%s&problem_id=%s&recent_topic_id=%s", 
                     URLEncoder.encode( comment, charset), 
                     URLEncoder.encode( user_id, charset), 
                     URLEncoder.encode( problem_id, charset), 
                     URLEncoder.encode( recent_topic_id, charset)
                     );             

            final URL url = new URL( myUrl + "?" + query );

            final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true); 
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            conn.connect();

            InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
            byte[] stream_buffer = new byte[8196];
            int readCount;
            StringBuilder stream_builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((readCount = stream.read(stream_buffer)) > -1) 
            {
                stream_builder.append(new String(stream_buffer, 0, readCount));
            }

            response = stream_builder.toString();       
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
                           // EXCEPTION HAPPENS HERE
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
           if ( result == null )
           {
                  // Do stuff
           }
        }
        else
        {               
      // Do stuff
    }        
}
```

Would anyone know why this happens and how to prevent it?

Comment: please do not add tags to subject

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing this on a physical device? This could be caused by having bad cell signal, or if the internet connection to your device or emulator is spotty. That would also explain why you can't reproduce it.